# How to delete a raster file after opening the raster in rioxarray

Tags: python, delete, rioxarray

I wanted to able to delete a temporary file, after opening it with rioxarray and start to process the final product.

I followed two ideas:

a)

```
with rioxarray.open_rasterio(temp_file) as raster:
  # do processing
  # save output
os.remove(file)
```

b)

```
raster = rioxarray.open_rasterio(temp_file)
# do processing
# save result somewhere
del raster
gc.collect()
os.remove(file)
```

Both didn't work because, the file was still opened. How can this temporary file be deleted?

Answer (score 0):

xarray leaves the files open unless you call `close`.
You can read more about it here: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/io.html

The `file_cache_maxsize` option is also useful to know about: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.set_options.html

Comment: The docs you link to states using a `with` statement automatically closes the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Either way should work with minor edits.

For both examples, `os.remove(file)` needs to be changed to `os.remove(temp_file)`. Idea a) should work after this since the context manager will close the dataset.

b) The dataset can be closed using [.close()](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.close.html#xarray.Dataset.close) as @snowman2 suggested

```
raster = rioxarray.open_rasterio(temp_file)
# do processing
# save result somewhere
raster.close()
os.remove(temp_file)
```

Note: If the dataset isn't closed by these methods, it may be due to an error documented in [How to overwrite raster opened with rioxarray.open_rasterio ?](https://github.com/corteva/rioxarray/issues/485)